# Synchronizing websocket connections to the same endpoint

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jetty-9, java-websocket

In my code, there is a websocket server that persists information to the database on behalf of the connected client.

I am using Jetty 9, Hibernate, and Postgres.

Essentially, when a client posts a data object via the websocket:

- The server deserializes the data
- Checks to see if the object already exists in the database, based on content
- If a match is found

  - The server will update the database row, and indicate that the item already exists
- Else

  - The server will create a new database row and indicate that the item was added.

In this system:

- An endpoint (ie., URL) corresponds to a single user principal
- Multiple connections to the same endpoint are allowed, meaning multiple connections from different clients to a single user.
- Data objects in the database are specific to a user

(This means that the server will only check rows belonging to the user for already-existing items)

This is all working well, except when 2 clients post the same data at precisely the same time.  Neither server instance knows about the other, and the database ends up with 2 rows that are the same, except for the server-generated ID.

How can I prevent the server from writing the same data at the same time?
I can't use a UNIQUE constraint in the database, because I actually do have to support having multiple rows with the same data, but posted at different times.

I can get all the other sessions attached to the same endpoint, using "session.getOpenSessions()".

Can I:

- Synchronize on the endpoint, somehow?
- Synchronize on something attached to the session?
- Do something with threading configuration?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can create a queue for each unique user and add the objects to this queue before inserting them into the database. Take a look at the [concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Comment: Any ideas on how to locate the queue for a specific user?  I would prefer to not have a (eg) hashmap of user to queue, as I want to support a rather large number of users.  Maybe some way to attach it to the endpoint?

Comment: Another question, is synchronizing in this way a really bad idea?

Comment: If you use a queue like [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) you don't need do do any synchronization yourself, this object is thread-safe, I can't offer any suggestions on how to implement this because I'm not familiar with `hibernate`, I'm not sure how a session is created and when it is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> Checks to see if the object already exists in the database, based on
>   content

You already define a unique constraint, meaning there's a column set combination that must be unique, so that when you match an existing row, you will update instead of inserting.

The database already offers a centralized concurrency control mechanism, so you should probably use an index on all the aforementioned columns.